# How parse json in tableview using swift?

Tags: json, parsing, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to read json date from url and parse it in Tableview using swift.  how can I make variable "jsonResult " as global ?

or please guide me how can I populate the tableview with this data from json.

```
let urlPath = "http://omanevents.net/OmanEventsApp/testPullDate.php"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {

            println("error")

        }else {

            let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary


            for var index = 0; index < jsonResult["Events"]?.count ; ++index {
                println(jsonResult["Events"]?[index]["Location"])
            }



        }

    })

    task.resume()
```

Comment: could it be that your events might me arriving as an array?

Comment: I dont know .. i am new to ios development. i need some help.. what format should I get into the tableview

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend that you have a look at this tutorial.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift

It shows you how to deal with core data but in the example it uses adding things to tableView, and saving data for use of the app at later stages. Ray Wnderlich is a great website.

Comment: On completion of this tutorial you should be able to add elements to any tableview.